# Firebase requests in completion handlers of other firebase requests?

Tags: ios, firebase

Is there a difference in the speed of getting 2 firebase requests completed if one is in the completion handler of the other, or if they both are done at started at the same time?

Comment: completion handler is good option for you but if you want to run both simultaneously then you can also add one request into background thread ...

Comment: you should take a look at some similar issues, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40385951/1459192

Comment: How about a simple code example? Otherwise it may or may not depend on your use case. In the case of a nested request, the second one definitely will not start until the first one has valid data from Firebase.